# Switch animation in Expansion panel not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a Material UI Switch in MUI Expansion Panel.I have maintained Switch's state in an array of objects and changing the state through a handler. The issue is that whenever I click the switch the state is changed correctly but the animation of switch doesn't show up until I collapse and expand the panel again manually. I looked in to some similar question and found that some people have used 'onClick' instead of 'onChange' but unfortunately the same isn't working for me.

```
export default function ControlledExpansionPanels() {


const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const initialValue = {
    isPlanMigration: false,
    restOfTheValues: "dummy Data"
  };
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([initialValue]);

  const handleplanMigrationChange = event => {
    let updatedValue = value;
    updatedValue.forEach((v, idx) => {
      if (idx === Number(event.target.name.split("_")[1])) {
        updatedValue[idx][event.target.name.split("_")[0]] =
          event.target.checked;
      }
    });
    setValue(updatedValue);
  };

  const addPanel = () => {
    setValue(value.concat([initialValue]));
  };

  const handleExpansionPanelChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {value.map((v, idx) => (
        <ExpansionPanel
          key={idx}
          expanded={expanded === `panel_${idx}`}
          onChange={handleExpansionPanelChange(`panel_${idx}`)}
        >
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>
              General settings
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
              I am an expansion panel
            </Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  label="Use Backenddiscover service"
                  checked={v.isPlanMigration}
                  onChange={handleplanMigrationChange}
                  color="primary"
                  name={`isPlanMigration_${idx}`}
                  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                />
              }
              label="Plan migration is required"
            />
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      ))}
      <IconButton
        color="primary"
        aria-label="Add API Config"
        component="span"
        onClick={addPanel}
      >
        <AddCircleIcon fontSize="large" />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried doing the same thing outside expansion panel and it seemed to work.

Here is the link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xe0vm?file=/demo.js:938-3241).
Any idea what might be the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state by copying value array to updatedValues array. Hence the issue.

[Your updated working codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-switch-issue-fix-dfm7g?file=/demo.js:1236-1560)

**Solution** - clone the array and then set the state

```js
const handleplanMigrationChange = event => {
    let updatedValue = [...value]; //<----- like this
    let target = event.target;
    updatedValue.forEach((v, idx) => {
      if (idx === Number(target.name.split("_")[1])) {
        updatedValue[idx][target.name.split("_")[0]] = target.checked;
      }
    });
    setValue(updatedValue);
  };
```

Note - As mentioned above, it is a good practice (and safe) to take a copy of the event.target and pass it to the forEach callback as react does [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I recently moved to react from angular, hence this state business is proving to be little difficult for me :)